# Prove that the likelihood function L(θ|x) is equivalent to maximizing log L(θ|x) where log is the natural logarithm

Tags: self-study, optimization, logarithm, likelihood

In other words, why

$\text{argmax} \text{ } L(\theta) = \text{argmax} \text{ } \text{log} \text{ } L(\theta)$
?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 6):

Additionnally to @forgottenscience answer, let consider the following (more intuitive, to my view) point:

First,

- $x \rightarrow \log(x)$ is a strictly increasing function
- Let call $\theta^*$ the value maximizing $L$ and $\nu^*$ the value maximizing $\log(L)$
  (i.e. $\theta^* =\arg\max_{\theta} L(\theta)$ and $\nu^* =\arg\max_{\nu} \log L(\nu)$).

Then, if $\nu^* \ne \theta^*$

1. then necessarily $L(\theta^*) > L(\nu^*)$ (remember that by definition $\theta^*$ is the value maximizing $L$),
2. then necessarily $\log(L(\theta^*)) > \log(L(\nu^*))$ (remember  $\log$ is a strictly increasing function)
3. which is impossible as, by definition, $\nu^*$ is the value that makes $\log(L(\nu))$ maximal

As a conclusion, $\nu^* == \theta^*$ i.e. $\arg\max L(\theta)=\arg\max \log L(\theta)$

And this is actually true for any other function that is strictly increasing, which may be convenient in many situation.

Comment: great answer! I always wondered about this!

Comment: not only more intuitive, but more general too as you don't need smoothness assumptions on $L(\theta)$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that the likelihood is differentiable and has a unique maximum. If $\theta^*$ is the argmax of $L(\theta)$, 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} L(\theta^*) = 0, $$
while it follows from the chain rule that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log L(\theta) = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} L(\theta)}{L(\theta)}, $$
so in particular
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log L(\theta^*) = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} L(\theta^*)}{L(\theta^*)} = 0,$$

showing that $\theta^*$ also is the argmax of $\log L(\theta)$.

Answer (score 2):

This is true for any strictly increasing function, and it is quite trivial to prove using the definitions of strict monotonicity and the argmax.  In fact, the result does not ]require either of the functions to be differentiable.  If $f$ is any [strictly increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) real function then, by definition, we have:

$$L > L'
\quad \quad \iff \quad \quad
 f(L) > f(L').$$

It follows that:

$$L \geqslant L'
\quad \quad \iff\quad \quad
 f(L) \geqslant f(L').$$

Thus, for any function $L:\Theta \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\text{arg max }} f(L(\theta))
&= \{ \theta \in \Theta | (\forall \theta' \in \Theta): f(L(\theta)) \geqslant f(L(\theta')) \} \\[6pt]
&= \{ \theta \in \Theta | (\forall \theta' \in \Theta): L(\theta) \geqslant L(\theta') \} \\[12pt]
&= \underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\text{arg max }} L(\theta), \\[6pt]
\end{aligned}$$

where the second step follows from the strict monotonicity of $f$ (in particular, the fact that $f(L) \geqslant f(L')$ implies $L \geqslant L'$).  Note also that for any non-decreasing function $f$ the same general process gives the weaker result that $\underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\text{arg max }} f(L(\theta)) \supseteq \underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\text{arg max }} L(\theta)$.